# PayPal Delayed Chained Payments: Releasing to secondary receivers returns "payKey AP-XXXX has already been used to make a payment"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments (1.117.1) gem in my Rails application to provide Delayed Chained Payments and Preapprovals. The payment process has three steps, whereas the above mentioned error pops up in the last one (as always). Here's the process:

1. A user pre-approves (using [PayPal's Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/)) an upcoming delayed chained payment. So far, everything works fine. I get a `preapprovalKey` back and save that.
2. When the time comes, I trigger a [Delayed Chained Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/) using the previously saved `preapprovalKey`. In this action I use the `actionType: "PAY_PRIMARY"`. Again, everything's fine and I get a `payKey` which I save.
3. Now, a bit later I want to release the money of the DCP from step 2 to the secondary receiver(s). To do that, I use the `payKey` I got back step 2.

And here comes the error:

> AP-XXXX has already been used to make a payment
>   The funny thing is that in contrast to this error message, the payment *was release successfully*, as depicted in the PayPal Dashboard.

It is of course no game breaker, since the Payment is still executed, but still there must be something wrong ...

The code for step 3 is the following:

```
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::API.new

@execute_payment = @api.build_execute_payment({
  payKey: @job.payKey
})

@response = @api.execute_payment(@execute_payment)
```

I am using PayPal in the Sandbox environment. The project is using Rails 4.2.3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you file a ticket with MTS support? You can the issue and give me the MTS ticket number here.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your execute call is getting hit twice in a row, and the response you're seeing is from the second one..??